# How to make annotation point draggable in MapKit using swift 2 and xcode 7?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

It is very frustrating to find the solution for this problem. I posted the whole code to understand the problem. Please help

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
class LocationViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var annotationPoint: MKPointAnnotation!
    var getMovedMapCenter: CLLocation!
    var myPinView:MKPinAnnotationView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        if(self.annotationPoint == nil)
        {
            self.annotationPoint = MKPointAnnotation()
            getMovedMapCenter =  CLLocation(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

             self.annotationPoint.coordinate = getMovedMapCenter.coordinate

            // self.annotationPoint.title = location_value
            //self.annotationPoint.subtitle = ""

            // println_debug(self.annotationPoint)

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotationPoint)

        }

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    //MARK:- View for Annotation
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myPin")

            pinAnnotationView.pinColor = .Purple
            pinAnnotationView.draggable = true
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
            pinAnnotationView.animatesDrop = true

            return pinAnnotationView
        }

        return nil
    }

    //MARK:- Annotation Changed State

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChangeDragState newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {

        print("hiii")


        //        println_debug("End State coordinates: \(self.annotationPoint.coordinate.latitude),\(self.annotationPoint.coordinate.longitude)")


        if(newState == .Ending)
        {


            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.annotationPoint.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.annotationPoint.coordinate.longitude)
            //    self.currentLocationNameA(center)

            //            dispatch_async(GlobalBackgroundQueue)
            //                {
            //
            //
            //            }
        }

    }

    //MARK:- update Not Get

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView,
        didFailToLocateUserWithError error: NSError)
    {
        // AppHelper.showALertWithTag(121, title: APP_NAME, message: "Failed to get location. Please check Location setting", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok", otherButtonTitle: nil)

    }




}
```

I got stuck in this code. Becasuse didChangeDragState Delegate never called. Please help me to find a better solution for this. I am new to swift; So its hard to convert the objective c code in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = false
```

This line solves my problem. Popup of showing "current location" was the main cause of this problem.

and these changes in code make it smooth dragging. Mehul and Vijay Answer help me in finding this solution.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChangeDragState newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
        switch (newState) {
        case .Ending, .Canceling:
            view.dragState = .None
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> The drag state typically changes in response to user interactions with
>   the annotation view. However, the annotation view itself is
>   responsible for changing that state as well.

**replace this method and try once. may be working fine**

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, didChangeDragState newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) {
    switch (newState) {
    case .Starting:
        view.dragState = .Dragging
    case .Ending, .Canceling:
        view.dragState = .None
    default: break
    }
}
```

**Replace you point annotation method with this one.**

```
let pa = MKPointAnnotation()
pa.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate
pa.title = placemark.name //or whatever title you like
self.mapView.addAnnotation(pa)
```

## for more , you can see [Code](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch21p744maps/ch34p1008maps/ViewController.swift) and [Another Sample Code](http://www.xcoding.it/modificare-e-trascinare-un-mkpointannotation-in-swift/)

Comment: Thanks Mehul. I am trying to use sample code. Hope it helps

Comment: sample is not working. It crashed in button action due to nil value of coordinates

Comment: Ohkey, we have to try another solution. give me time. i will Give you perfect solution whenever i become Available.

Comment: Ok. I am waiting for your help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Mehul for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId12 = "pin12"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)

    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId12)
        pinView.image = UIImage(named:"pin-1250.png")
        pinView.canShowCallout = false
        pinView.draggable = true
    }
    else {

        pinView.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
```

Try this code.

Comment: But this mehtod is not calling. this is the main problem

Comment: It seems in your `viewDidLoad()` method you missed to set mapView delegate. Try to add `self.mapView.delegate = self`

Comment: delegate is set through storyboard. Pin is not moving only map is moving